# Authentication failed using instance:connect in Apache Karaf 3.0.2

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf

Can someone please help me why this call is no longer working in Apache Karaf 3.0.2. I verified that it was working in version 3.0.1. All instances are up and running, but I am unable to connect to one of my instances directly from the command line.

```
su - karaf -c " client -h localhost -a 8101 -u karaf -r 50 -d 2 \" instance:connect -u karaf -p karaf test1 \\\" feature:repo-list \\\" \" "
Logging in as karaf
455 [sshd-SshClient[bea319b]-nio2-thread-1] WARN org.apache.sshd.client.keyverifier.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier - Server at [localhost/127.0.0.1:8101, DSA, b6:f6:d6:3f:8b:2f:ad:a4:0f:3f:3d:c3:7b:96:fd:ae] presented unverified {} key: {}
Connecting to host localhost on port 8103
Connecting to unknown server. Automatically adding to known hosts.
Storing the server key in known_hosts.
Error executing command: Authentication failed
```

The call is part of an automated process and I cannot connect to a specific instance directly. Is there any specific configuration required, that was not necessary in 3.0.1?

**UPDATE #1:**

I have added the verbose option... Does it give you any hints what to do?

```
client -v -h localhost -a 8101 -u karaf -r 50 -d 2 " instance:connect -u karaf test1 \" feature:repo-list \" "
39 [main] INFO org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils - BouncyCastle not registered, using the default JCE provider
Logging in as karaf
367 [sshd-SshClient[bea319b]-nio2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Client session created
380 [main] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Start flagging packets as pending until key exchange is done
383 [sshd-SshClient[bea319b]-nio2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Server version string: SSH-2.0-SSHD-CORE-0.12.0
384 [sshd-SshClient[bea319b]-nio2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Kex: server->client [aes128-ctr, hmac-sha1, none] {} {}
384 [sshd-SshClient[bea319b]-nio2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Kex: client->server [aes128-ctr, hmac-sha1, none] {} {}
444 [sshd-SshClient[bea319b]-nio2-thread-1] WARN org.apache.sshd.client.keyverifier.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier - Server at [localhost/127.0.0.1:8101, DSA, 22:8b:f8:9d:bc:c6:40:d8:fe:52:aa:90:c0:f2:70:ec] presented unverified {} key: {}
457 [sshd-SshClient[bea319b]-nio2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Dequeing pending packets
524 [sshd-SshClient[bea319b]-nio2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthServiceNew - Received SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE
568 [sshd-SshClient[bea319b]-nio2-thread-2] INFO org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthServiceNew - Received SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS
Connecting to host localhost on port 8102
Error executing command: Authentication failed
```

**UPDATE #2:**

I switched the logger to DEBUG and I found this exception:

```
2015-01-15 11:28:48,920 | DEBUG | 5]-nio2-thread-1 | ClientSessionImpl                | 28 - org.apache.sshd.core - 0.12.0 | Received SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT
2015-01-15 11:28:48,920 | INFO  | 5]-nio2-thread-1 | ClientUserAuthServiceNew         | 28 - org.apache.sshd.core - 0.12.0 | Received SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE
2015-01-15 11:28:48,920 | DEBUG | 5]-nio2-thread-1 | ClientUserAuthServiceNew         | 28 - org.apache.sshd.core - 0.12.0 | Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive, password, publickey
2015-01-15 11:28:48,922 | DEBUG | 5]-nio2-thread-1 | Nio2Session                      | 28 - org.apache.sshd.core - 0.12.0 | Caught exception, now calling handler
2015-01-15 11:28:48,922 | WARN  | 5]-nio2-thread-1 | ClientSessionImpl                | 28 - org.apache.sshd.core - 0.12.0 | Exception caught
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable set
at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.KarafAgentFactory.createClient(KarafAgentFactory.java:71)
at org.apache.sshd.client.auth.UserAuthPublicKey.init(UserAuthPublicKey.java:78)
at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthServiceNew.tryNext(ClientUserAuthServiceNew.java:212)
at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthServiceNew.processUserAuth(ClientUserAuthServiceNew.java:178)
at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthServiceNew.process(ClientUserAuthServiceNew.java:131)
at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthService.process(ClientUserAuthService.java:80)
at org.apache.sshd.common.session.AbstractSession.doHandleMessage(AbstractSession.java:399)
at org.apache.sshd.common.session.AbstractSession.handleMessage(AbstractSession.java:295)
at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl.handleMessage(ClientSessionImpl.java:256)
at org.apache.sshd.common.session.AbstractSession.decode(AbstractSession.java:731)
at org.apache.sshd.common.session.AbstractSession.messageReceived(AbstractSession.java:277)
at org.apache.sshd.common.AbstractSessionIoHandler.messageReceived(AbstractSessionIoHandler.java:54)
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session$1.onCompleted(Nio2Session.java:187)
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session$1.onCompleted(Nio2Session.java:173)
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler$1.run(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:32)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_65]
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler.completed(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:30)[28:org.apache.sshd.core:0.12.0]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:157)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:553)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:275)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:296)[:1.7.0_65]
at java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel.read(AsynchronousSocketChannel.java:407)[:1.7.0_65]
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session.startReading(Nio2Session.java:173)[28:org.apache.sshd.core:0.12.0]
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session$1.onCompleted(Nio2Session.java:189)
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session$1.onCompleted(Nio2Session.java:173)
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler$1.run(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:32)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_65]
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler.completed(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:30)[28:org.apache.sshd.core:0.12.0]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:157)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:553)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:275)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:296)[:1.7.0_65]
at java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel.read(AsynchronousSocketChannel.java:407)[:1.7.0_65]
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session.startReading(Nio2Session.java:173)[28:org.apache.sshd.core:0.12.0]
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session$1.onCompleted(Nio2Session.java:189)
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session$1.onCompleted(Nio2Session.java:173)
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler$1.run(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:32)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_65]
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler.completed(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:30)[28:org.apache.sshd.core:0.12.0]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:157)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:553)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:275)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:296)[:1.7.0_65]
at java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel.read(AsynchronousSocketChannel.java:407)[:1.7.0_65]
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session.startReading(Nio2Session.java:173)[28:org.apache.sshd.core:0.12.0]
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session$1.onCompleted(Nio2Session.java:189)
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session$1.onCompleted(Nio2Session.java:173)
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler$1.run(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:32)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_65]
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler.completed(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:30)[28:org.apache.sshd.core:0.12.0]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:157)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:553)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:275)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:296)[:1.7.0_65]
at java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel.read(AsynchronousSocketChannel.java:407)[:1.7.0_65]
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session.startReading(Nio2Session.java:173)[28:org.apache.sshd.core:0.12.0]
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Connector$1.onCompleted(Nio2Connector.java:53)[28:org.apache.sshd.core:0.12.0]
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Connector$1.onCompleted(Nio2Connector.java:46)[28:org.apache.sshd.core:0.12.0]
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler$1.run(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:32)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_65]
at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler.completed(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:30)[28:org.apache.sshd.core:0.12.0]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218)[:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)[:1.7.0_65]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_65]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_65]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_65]
```

Comment: might want to ask this on the karaf users mailinglist, it got a much broader audience there

Comment: Already done, but I got no responses so far.

Comment: this is because you didn't subscribe to the mailinglist ...
http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Authentication-failed-using-instance-connect-in-Apache-Karaf-3-0-2-td4037780.html

Comment: Now I am subscribed. I have deleted another post (http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Using-individual-key-file-with-karaf-client-fails-td4037802.html) and posted it again. It's still pending. Is there something more required?

Comment: It's working... Maybe I was just too impatient. Sorry!